# Error using shadcn-ui to add a button in a Next.js TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, next.js, syntax-error, npx

I encountered an error while attempting to add a button using the npx shadcn-ui@latest add button command in a Next.js TypeScript project. The error message is as follows:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:140:18)
at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)

I am working on a Next.js project with TypeScript, and I tried to add a button using the npx shadcn-ui@latest add button command. However, the command resulted in a SyntaxError with an unexpected token '?'. The error points to a file named index.js within the shadcn-ui module, specifically at line 2.

I expected the command to add a button using the shadcn-ui library to execute successfully without any syntax errors.

folder structure:

└── ai-saas-app
└── .eslintrc.json
└── app
└── favicon.ico
└── globals.css
└── page.tsx
└── components
└── components.json
└── lib
└── utils.ts
└── next-env.d.ts
└── next.config.js
└── package-lock.json
└── package.json
└── postcss.config.js
└── public
└── next.svg
└── vercel.svg
└── README.md
└── tailwind.config.js
└── tailwind.config.ts
└── tsconfig.json

```
Steps Taken:

I created a Next.js TypeScript project.
I ran the command npx shadcn-ui@latest add button to add a button component from the shadcn-ui library.
The command installation process took place, but it resulted in the SyntaxError mentioned above.
```